# Как взять значения из каждого select'a?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Создаются блоки через цикл, в каждом блоке есть select. 
Подскажите, как при клике на кнопку, взять выбранные значения из всех созданных select'ов?

```
<div v-for="attribute in attributes" class="col">
 {{ attribute.name }}
 <select ref="selectedVariation" class="form-control">
     <option selected>---</option>
     <option v-for="variation in attribute.variations"
     :key="variation.id"
       :value="variation.id">
      {{ variation.name }}
     </option>
  </select>
</div>`
<button class="btn btn-success">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ:

```js
awesomeMethod() {
  var length = this.$refs.selectedVariation.length

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    this.variations[i] = this.$refs.selectedVariation[i]['value']
    // console.log(this.$refs.selectedVariation[i]['value'])
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
collectValues() {
    this.collectedValues = this.$refs.selectedVariation.map(item => item.value);
}
```